# How do I ensure tearDown is called (in the case of an uncaught exception in the test) with nosetests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I have a test-case with both a `setUp` and `tearDown` method:

```
TESTCONF = SafeConfigParser(...)
ENGINE = create_engine(TESTCONF.get('database', 'dsn'))

class TestBase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.config = TESTCONF
        self.connection = ENGINE.connect()
        self.trans = self.connection.begin()
        self.session = Session(bind=self.connection)

    def tearDown(self):
        print "post teardown 0", ENGINE.pool.status()
        self.trans.rollback()
        print "post teardown 1", ENGINE.pool.status()
        self.session.close()
        print "post teardown 2", ENGINE.pool.status()
        self.connection.close()
        print "post teardown 3", ENGINE.pool.status(), "\n"
```

All DB related test-cases inherit from this class. It seems as if `tearDown` is not always called. I am having trouble to localize the error. At one point, the test-runner hangs on

```
self.connection = ENGINE.connect()
```

I assume that the `close` method was not always called to release a connection from the pool.

Any ideas what to look for?

**Update:** I how added some print statements (also added them in the example code above), and my initial though was correct. Some connections are not properly closed and are not handed back to the pool. This happens for all "Errors" (not "Failures") in the tests. The following block shows the output I get using the above `tearDown` method (cut off prematurely for brevity). As you can see, the lines with errors (those starting with `Epre` instead of `.pre`) do not call any `tearDown` lines. Not even the `post tearDown 0` message shows up!

I have now traced back the error to using `self.assertRaisesRegEx` instead of `self.assertRaisesRegExp`, so the exception is raised inside the *unit-test*, not inside the tested code!

```
pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -5 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
'TestCommonBase' object has no attribute 'assertRaisesRegex'
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
'TestCommonBase' object has no attribute 'assertRaisesRegex'
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0 

.SSpre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 0
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
ESpre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -4 Current Checked out connections: 1
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -3 Current Checked out connections: 2
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -3 Current Checked out connections: 2
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -2 Current Checked out connections: 3
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -2 Current Checked out connections: 3
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -1 Current Checked out connections: 4
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -1 Current Checked out connections: 4
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 0 Current Checked out connections: 5
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 0 Current Checked out connections: 5
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 1 Current Checked out connections: 6
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 1 Current Checked out connections: 6
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 2 Current Checked out connections: 7
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 2 Current Checked out connections: 7
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 3 Current Checked out connections: 8
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 3 Current Checked out connections: 8
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 4 Current Checked out connections: 9
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 4 Current Checked out connections: 9
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 5 Current Checked out connections: 10
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 5 Current Checked out connections: 10
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 6 Current Checked out connections: 11
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 6 Current Checked out connections: 11
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 7 Current Checked out connections: 12
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 7 Current Checked out connections: 12
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 8 Current Checked out connections: 13
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 8 Current Checked out connections: 13
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 9 Current Checked out connections: 14
Epre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 9 Current Checked out connections: 14
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 15
post teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 15
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 15
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 15
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 14 

.pre setup Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 14
post connect Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 15
Epost teardown 0 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 15
post teardown 1 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 15
post teardown 2 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 15
post teardown 3 Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: 10 Current Checked out connections: 14
```

### Additional details:

For the sake of this question, I wrote a very small reproducible example. Unfortunately that one did not exhibit this behaviour:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
    """
    Example test case meant to demonstrate that ``tearDown`` is not called.

    It turns out, in this case, ``tearDown`` *is* called as expected!
    """

    def setUp(self):
        print "setup"

    def tearDown(self):
        print "tearDown"

    def test_failing(self):
        print int('yes')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So what makes this example different from my real-world code? Why is `tearDown` called in the simple example, but not in my production code?

I will continue to investigate...

Comment: It seems you are making a lot of assumptions here. What, exactly, makes you think that tearDown is not being called? If you put a print statement in the "tearDown" method, or some other statement that is easily identified as having been run (like writing to a file), do you see that statement called?

Comment: @MarkHildreth I'm sorry, I had to write the question in a hurry (train to catch). I tried with a print statement. I saw no output. I will try writing to a file once I'm back at the office. Nosetests intercepts stdout, so printing might not be a reliable debugging technique in this case.

Comment: @MarkHildreth I had now more time to investigate and added more details to the question. I am still quite puzzled as to why this is happening. I will try to write a self-contained example to reproduce the behaviour. But it seems that the "simple" demo-code is not enough to trigger the error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect that `tearDown` is not called, then I can propose you to use context manager for resource allocation in your tests. The `with` statement guarantees that if the `__enter__()` method returns without an error, then `__exit__()` will always be called.

Here is your example modified to use context manager for connection allocation:

```
TESTCONF = SafeConfigParser(...)
ENGINE = create_engine(TESTCONF.get('database', 'dsn'))

class DBConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, engine):
        self.engine = engine

    def __enter__(self):
        self.connection = engine.connect()
        self.trans = self.connection.begin()
        self.session = Session(bind=self.connection)
        # return value can be accessed using `as` directive
        return self.connection, self.trans, self.session

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback):
        self.trans.rollback()
        self.session.close()
        self.connection.close()


class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.config = TESTCONF

    def run(self, result=None):
        with DBConnection(ENGINE) as db_conn:
            self.connection, self.trans, self.session = db_conn
            super(MyTest, self).run(result)
```

Also you can use contextlib if DBConnection class seems too bulky:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def DBConnection(engine):
    connection = engine.connect()
    trans = connection.begin()
    session = Session(bind=connection)
    yield connection, trans, session
    trans.close()
    session.close()
    connection.close()
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I'll give it a shot. What worries me most though is the fact that `tearDown` is supposed to be called no matter what. Using a context-manager seems redundant. But it's worth a try.

Comment: FYI: I have not tried your solution yet, but in the mean-time added more details to the questions about my findings.

Comment: Well, after fiddling around and not getting anywhere I am now using your solution. I will accept in a few days. I'm giving other people a chance to chime in as well.

Comment: Hello me-from-the-past :) The solution with `@contextmanager` is clean, but it will also fail to properly close the session unless adding a `try/finally` block around the `yield` statement. And closing the objects inside that `finally` block!